# silly C++ syntax has not been declared

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, namespaces, cross-compiling

I'm trying to take a Qt C++ project originally written for Windows and cross compile it for embedded Linux. Now this program compiles find and works on Windows, so this problem must be something OS specific (which I didn't think happend with Qt code) or configuration related, but I'm having a hard time tracking it down because I don't fully understand C++ syntax.

my make command:

> arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c -march=armv7-a -marm -mthumb-interwork
>   -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a8 -O2 -O3 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DCHL80Net -DPHASE_TO_NEUTRAL -DCHL80NET -DCANLCD_BUILD -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../mkspecs/qws/linux-am335x-g++ -I. -I../include/QtCore -I../include/QtGui -I../include/QtXml -I../include -I. -IApp -IApp/Model/ModelSim -IApp/Model -I. -IPages -IApp/GUI/Widgets -IApp/GUI/Pages -IApp/GUI -IApp/GUI/Widgets -IApp/GUI/Pages/Util -IApp/GUI/Pages -IApp/Log4Qt -I.obj -o .obj/CanInterface.o App/Can/CanInterface.cpp

The error:

> App/Can/CanInterface.cpp: In member function ‘void
>   CanInterface::closeConnection()’: App/Can/CanInterface.cpp:68:5:
>   error: ‘::close’ has not been declared make: *** [.obj/CanInterface.o]
>   Error 1

Here's the line of code in question:

```
void CanInterface::closeConnection()
{
    ::close(m_socket);
    m_socket = -1;
```

I thought this didn't look like valid code at all at first, but I don't really know C++ so I had to do a little research, it seems like this `::function()` syntax is to ensure resolution occurs from the global namespace instead of the local one.

So what I'm trying to find out is what namespace should have declaired this `close()` function. If my understanding of this code is correct I don't need to look in the `CanInterface` class for the undeclaired function, but it's parent class?

In the header file for the `CanInterface` class I found this:

```
class CanInterface : public QObject 
{
        Q_OBJECT
```

which I *think* means that it inharents from a `QObject` class. So:

1. Am I on the right track?
2. How do I know if I need to look at the `QObject` class for the missing `close()` function or if I need to keep going up? Does `::close` somehow tell me how many levels of nested classes I need to search through?
3. Any other ideas or tips for further investigating this?

Comment: In answer to #3:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @John maybe some day I'll have time to read more, but for now I just have to get the job done. I'm a C programmer, this is outside my element and I *shouldn't* have to touch C++ again... i hope...

Comment: Can you find out in a windows IDE what `close` is supposed to be?

Comment: [`::close` should be declared in `<unistd.h>`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/close).

Comment: @OlafDietsche He knows what `close()` does in a C program, but not that `::close()` in a C++ program is intended to invoke the same function.

Comment: @Casey, Mike Ok, sorry for the noise.

Comment: @Casey - OK, that's exactly the answer I needed. `::close()` is `close()` got it. And I see `unistd.h` was not included in the `extern "C"` list, that is the problem. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ encapsulates names in namespaces to avoid naming collisions. It's somewhat analagous to the C practice of prepending a prefix specific to a library to the names of functions in that library, e.g., `my_library_foo()` in C might be called `my_library::foo()` in C++. When `::` appears at the beginning of a name, it means that name is *fully qualified*: it is looked up beginning from the global namespace instead of the current/enclosing namespace, much like with absolute (`/etc/passwd/`) vs. relative (`foo/bar`) file names.

So the name `::close` is intended to resolve to the close function declared in the global namespace, the one which would be put there by including `<unistd.h>` on a POSIX system.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I guess I was equating `::` to `..` in my head and thinking it would be "up one level" instead of literally  a "top most" function call. That was a very helpful explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct, in that `::some_function()` calls a function from the global scope.

This includes all `C` library or system functions. You can lookup global functions on a *nix system with `man`, e.g.

```
man close
```

which gives on my Ubuntu

```
NAME
       close - close a file descriptor

SYNOPSIS
       #include <unistd.h>

       int close(int fd);
```

So, to fix your compile error, you must include `unistd.h` somewhere in your C++ source or in a surrounding header file.

You can get the same information, when you google for [man close](https://www.google.de/search?q=man+close), e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/2/close